# What the raven said?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

<sub>*This riddle has been approved in the [Riddle Sandbox](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5276).*</sub>

---

Each line is a clue to the same word. For a complete solution, you must explain every line.

- With nudity all around me, I help with inventory.
- With my superhero garb, I'm popular with tourists.
- A part of me covers your nether regions.
- In action, I interpreted unreadable text.
- I'm the reason you're no longer with us.
- With my childhood sweetheart, I am an ancient book.
- If something is no longer relevant, bring me in, and you'll find a way to get by.
- I never pay in advance.

***Who am I?***

Comment: Glad to see this one on the main site :). I remember the answer but hey, who am I to ruin the fun! Let's see if people can find it :)

Comment: These puzzles are removed from the sandbox, aren't they??

Comment: @Sid I couldn't find this one on there

Comment: @Areeb It's possible he removed it from there so no one would cheat, but I remember seeing this one in there.

Comment: @dcfyj that's what I was pointing out to sid, since he was expressing concern about people cheating

Comment: Dog goes woof. Cat goes meow. Bird goes tweet and mouse goes squeak... What does the raven say?

Comment: @Sid The procedure is to delete the question from the sandbox after it garners enough votes, in order to keep the sandbox from getting too full.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got 'em!

The answer is:

> "cod"

What did the raven say?

> Cawed

With nudity all around me, I help with inventory.

> bare + cod = barcode

With my superhero garb, I'm popular with tourists.

> Cape Cod

A part of me covers your nether regions.

> codpiece

In action, I interpreted unreadable text.

> decoded

I'm the reason you're no longer with us.

> COD = cause of death

With my childhood sweetheart, I am an ancient book.

> codex (cod + ex)

If something is no longer relevant, bring me in, and you'll find a way to get by.

> passe + cod = passcode

I never pay in advance.

> COD = Cash On Delivery

Comment: Well done! That didn't take long!

Comment: It was Engineer Toast's comment that put me on the right track.  Once I had (rot13) "Pncr Pbq" the rest just fell into place.

Comment: Updated per your comment, GPR.  Thanks for a great puzzle!